# How to get records for the values when there was increase in salary

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I want to check if the salary of an employee has salary increased between 100 and 500.

```
Employee   Salary   Serial No    ID     Criteria
James       500      1         110      Inc
James       800      2         110      NA
James       900      3         110      NA
James       1200     4         110      Inc
James       1100     5         110      NA
James       1500     6         110      NA
Jim         1000     1         112      Inc
Jim         1100     2         112      NA
Jim         1300     3         112      NA
Jim         1500     4         112      NA
Jim         1900     5         112      Inc
Jim         1800     6         112      NA
Jim         2200     7         112      NA
```

--ID is unique to each employee and serial no is the sequence of events
 occurrence for the employee in terms of salary increase or decrease. I need to find the serial number which had previous criteria as Inc ( does not necessarily have to be previous row, as long as it satisfies the criteria of 100 and 500) and salary increase between 100 and 500. Please note we might have multiple records satisfying the criteria but I need only one which ever is the first one which had increase. Also, we may have salary decrease as well ,I don't need to display it rather display the next record which has satisfying criteria. We need to look only we have criteria as Inc and then look for values which satisfy the range between 100 and 500, and get the first value.

--Desired Output

```
Employee   Salary   Serial No    ID     Criteria

 James       800      2         110      NA
 James       1500     6         110      NA
 Jim         1100     2         112      NA
 Jim         2200     7         112      NA
```

Comment: I don't get your problem at all.  Your desired results seem to have nothing to do with the problem you have stated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this by incrementally adding information to your records via several entries in a `with` clause.

In the first `select` I just reproduced your example data. The end result will produce all the intermediary information so you can see the logic that has been applied:

```
with salary(Employee, Salary, SerialNo, ID,  Criteria) as (
    select 'James',   500,    1,        110, 'Inc'  union all
    select 'James',   800,    2,        110, 'NA'   union all
    select 'James',   900,    3,        110, 'NA'   union all
    select 'James',   1200,   4,        110, 'Inc'  union all
    select 'James',   1100,   5,        110, 'NA'   union all
    select 'James',   1500,   6,        110, 'NA'   union all
    select 'Jim',     1000,   1,        112, 'Inc'  union all
    select 'Jim',     1100,   2,        112, 'NA'   union all
    select 'Jim',     1300,   3,        112, 'NA'   union all
    select 'Jim',     1500,   4,        112, 'NA'   union all
    select 'Jim',     1900,   5,        112, 'Inc'  union all
    select 'Jim',     1800,   6,        112, 'NA'   union all
    select 'Jim',     2200,   7,        112, 'NA'
), 
extended as (
    select salary.*,
           count(case Criteria when 'Inc' then 1 end) over 
                (partition by Employee order by SerialNo) incGroup
    from   salary
),
extended2 as (
    select extended.*,
           first_value(Salary) over
                (partition by Employee, incGroup order by SerialNo) incSalary
    from   extended
),
extended3 as (
    select extended2.*,
           row_number() over
                (partition by Employee, incGroup order by SerialNo) rn
    from   extended2
    where  Salary - incSalary between 100 and 500
)
select * from extended3 where rn = 1;
```

See it run on [rextester.com](http://rextester.com/BTDGN10936)

NB/ You might want to partition by `ID` where I did it by `Employee` if indeed the `ID` is the Employee's key.

Comment: Thank You for providing ideas, it really helped !